# Background img shows up in Chrome but not in Safari

Tags: html, css, image, background, safari

I have a search input

```
<input class="searchico" type="search" results="5" id="search" placeholder="" autosave="bfyudsaibduisbvy1213">
```

For the class searchico my css is as follows:

```
.searchico
{
    font-weight: 200;
    width:10px;
    position:relative;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background: white url('images/searchico.png') right no-repeat;
}
```

In chrome it works perfectly but in Safari it's just a blank white search bar...

[image: Chrome image where it's a search icon and if you click on it, it expands into a search bar with the icon on the right side]

[image: This is what happens in Safari... just an ugly blank search bar]

I want it to look just like the Apple website's search ico (transition into search bar when clicked). How can I achieve this in Safari if using css background image doesn't work?

Comment: You're using `type="search"` rather than `type="text"` therefore resorting to the browsers default styling for that input type. Try adding the property `-webkit-appearance: none;` and see if that works?

Comment: You are indeed correct. This is a handy trick I will for sure keep in mind for the future. I keep forgetting browsers have default styling that need to be overruled. Thank you!!!!